# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Visual Studio 2015RC CS0234 and CS0103 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

There are similar Qs on SO but I could find none relating to my specifics

The ASP.NET MVC file new project builds and runs ok but in the editor I have red squigglies all over the place with numerous CS0234:
"the type or namespace 'MVC' does not exist" and CS0103: the name xxxx does not exist in the current context. Where xxxx is ViewBag, Scripts, RenderSection etc.

On adding a model and referencing items on that model using @Model then this too fails in the same way in the editor. Opening existing projects from vs2013 in 2015 also behaves the same. I can see local copies of System.Web.Helpers.dll and System.Web..Mvc.dll in the local bin directory but the editor cannot be referencing these.

I have tried deleting and reinstalling MVC (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc) manually using nuget to no avail.

os: windows 8.1 pro

Maybe a known bug? Hope someone can throw some light on this.

Web Config (extract):

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
```

Packages (extract):

```xml
<packages>

  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" userInstalled="true" />

</packages>
```

Thought I had fixed this (see below faux fix 1 below) but the c# code completion/intellisense was still broken. Reinstalling VS made no difference.

**faux fix 1**
squigglies + cs0234 errors disappeared but no c# intellisense/code completion

1. went to programs and features to modify the current vs settings to remove just the web tools
2. almost immediately aborted the above  - the installer aborted with no changes  except maybe setting a restore point. Thought it was prudent to go back into vs and uninstall web essentials extension first!
3. in vs uninstalled web essentials
4. on restarting vs had an error relating to chutzpah extension ( error details below) which I uninstalled
5. Opened vs again to check it still worked - newed up an asp.net mvc 5 project (so at this stage no changes have been made to the vs installed components)  and everything was working no more errors in the editor all squigglies gone!
6. reloaded above extensions and everything still works

error details (from %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml)

```xml
<entry>
    <record>389</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 19:45:05.396</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [ChutzpahVS2012Package]</description>
    <guid>{A523D775-1341-4F21-A950-8C716E5628C9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>390</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 19:45:05.396</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [ChutzpahVS2012Package]</description>
    <guid>{A523D775-1341-4F21-A950-8C716E5628C9}</guid>
    <hr>80070002</hr>
    <errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

end of faux fix 1

Comment: I'm not clear - does this happen when you create a new MVC5 project too?

Comment: @Simon McKenzie - yes  file new project

Comment: [This article on MVC4](http://colinmackay.scot/tag/asp-net-mvc-4/) suggests setting the `System.Web.Mvc` reference to "Copy Local". Does that help?

Comment: @Simon McKenzie -  Just added an answer as you commented - problem has disappeared for now.  'Copy Local' appears to be set by default ( although that is now with things working) -   thx for looking at this. All v. odd somehow I have reset something

Comment: @Simon McKenzie - spoke too soon the fix above did not work - deleted my answer and added an update to the question to clarify things tried.

Answer (score 0):

More thorough uninstall followed by a manual clean up and finally a fresh install fixed the issue, steps I took were:

1. reset settings
2. uninstall updates and extensions
3. uninstall vs - do not repair (check if ssdt tooling v 14.X has been removed  from programs + features)
4. uninstall the Microsoft android emulator
5. clean contents of:  [documents]/visual studio 2015/Settings
6. remove directory:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
7. clean-up android pieces - the installer uses its own copy of the android sdks which are not needed if you have an existing local install. VS can be configured to use these.
8. reinstall android emulator from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers
   \VSEmu_Android\5BB714E7FFD81CCD122D7489709480E863AE7999EB5C9AF862033F98B106DACB

This felt like a sledge hammer to crack a very small nut!